# What is the meaning of this below code? I am just beginner

Tags: javascript, angular

I am having problem with understanding the below code

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-heroes',
   templateUrl: './heroes.component.html',
   styleUrls: ['./heroes.component.css']
})
export class HeroesComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

My doubts is, What we are doing in export clss HeroesComponent section? and what are OnInit,constructor and ngOnInit?

Comment: you should be reading the official angular doc , everything is explained with samples  there

Answer (score 0):

Constructor, ngOnInit both are nothing but methods inside a class.
In general, constructor method will be called when ever instance of the class( i.e. component here) is created whereas ngOnInit will be called after DOM is created for the component.

More details,

Angular bootstrap process consists of the two major stages:

- constructing components tree
- running change detection

The constructor of the component is called when Angular constructs components tree. 
All life cycle hooks including ngOnInit are called as part of the change detection phase.

Uses:
Constructor is mostly used for dependency injection and any initialization with respect to the component are initialized in ngOnInit. In order to use ngOnInit method we need to implement OnInit interface from angular library.

Comment: please accept or upvote the answer if it has solved your concern

Answer (score 0):

From your question, I derive that you are new to Angular community.

OnInit is an interface.
In the typings file lifecycle_hooks.d.ts it is defined as

> export interface OnInit {
>       ngOnInit(): void; }

It's use ->  Lifecycle hook that is called after data-bound properties of directives and components are initialized.(or just before initialization, if you want to do some task, you write in this ngOnInit() {
  } method)

One thing to note is (might not be very useful in your case) is the parents OnInit is called before it's child. Also it is invoked only once when the
 * directive is instantiated.

constructor() is a method which will be called when Angular creates an object of your class.

Just like OnInit there are multiple lifecycle hooks.The way you use it is just like OnInit -> implement the interface and define the method, and you can write down any code that you want to run at that life cycle stage of component.
Below is the order in which these hooks are called.

[image]

Do mark it as resolved if I was able to solve your problem.